# 配列を引数としたPostgresql配列データ検索方法について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Ruby on Rails にてWebアプリを作成しております。初学者のため回答に必要な前提条件等が抜けておればご指摘頂けますと幸いです。

ユーザーが指定する条件に基づいてデータベースのテーブルを検索するクエリを作成しているのですが、以下の条件で最も簡潔な書き方をご教示いただけないでしょうか？？

①Postgresqlデータベースの中に配列（ex. ["a", "b", "c"]）が格納されている列があり、この列データと②の検索条件を照合してデータを検索する

②ユーザーが指定した条件（チェックボックスを使用）は配列で取得している状況 ex. ["a", "c"]

①②の配列に格納されるデータ数は必ずしも一致しないが、共に7つという上限あり。

クエリ抽出条件としては、②の配列に含まれる文字のどれか１つでも①の配列に含まれていれば、データを抽出する。

現状、モデル内に以下のようなscopeを記述し、データの抽出を行おうとしています。

```
scope :search_by_preference, ->(num) { where("? = ANY(preference_num)", num)}
```

しかしながら、こちらのプレイスホルダーでは、配列を引数として渡すことができません。
なお、引数が１つ（ユーザーの選択した条件が１つ）のときは問題なくクエリは機能しております。

以上、何卒よろしくお願いします

Comment: 配列同士のオーバーラップを調べれば良いのではないでしょうか。`where("preference_num && '?'::int[]", num)` 参照: [PostgreSQL: Documentation: 9.1: Array Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。頂いた質問内容を試す中で、データベースが文字列としてインポート（CSV）されていることに気づきましたので、質問内容を修正しました。引用先のページを確認したところ、特にintegerでなくとも&&での比較が使えそうだったので試してみましたが、「PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: array value must start with "{" or dimension information」というエラーが出てしまいます。

Comment: 比較時に渡す引数となる配列の形式を{"a", "c" }と角括弧に変換はできないと思うのですが、どのように解決すればよいのでしょうか？？

Comment: `where("preference_num && ARRAY[?]", num)` にするとどうなりますでしょうか？

Comment: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying[] && text[] toiuというエラーになりました。また、引数に配列を指定する際には引数の前にアスタリスクが必要という記述がありましたので、試したところ、wrong number of bind variables (2 for 1)というエラーが帰ってきています。

Comment: エラーメッセージからすると、`where("preference_num && ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", num)` とするとよいかもしれません。

Comment: 期待通りの結果を取得できました！長々とお付き合いいただき本当にありがとうございます。これはpostgresqlのデータ型がcharacter varying[]であるため、引数を明示的に可変長文字列に指定したということですね。今後はデータ型にももっと気をつけたいと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

上述のコメントにもありますが、postgresqlのデータ型がcharacter varying[]であるため、引数を明示的に可変長文字列に指定することで解決しました。

```
where("preference_num && ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", num)
```